# Make parents of how much I earn?

Tags: causative-make

I saw the following in a Facebook post, but I don't know what it means:

> Make parents of how much I earn.

> Make parents of how happy I am.

Is something missing?

Comment: Both the sentences seem totally incorrect to me. I mean I can't even decipher the meaning of what they meant to say in the first place.

Comment: I am closing this question because it's on incorrect sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something is missing. In fact probably three somethings are missing. To make that a grammatical sentence, it needs to be something like “**I should** make **my** parents **aware** of how much I earn”.

Comment: That is actually four somethings...